# Не работает функция window() в VS 2017

Tags: c, visual-studio-2015

Подключил #include < conio.h > , но многие функции, а именно window(),gotoxy() не определяются... Пользуюсь VS 2017.

Comment: А и не должны, нет их там.

Comment: В каком заголовочном файле они есть?

Comment: Вероятно, ни в одном из стандартных.